# Calling Stored procedure with output

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been trying to retrieve some information from my database, and also retrieve the return value. I know the Stored Procedure works fine.

The code I use is a modified piece I use for registering the user. It's going wrong at the cmd.ExecuteReader part of my code.

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //Actions after Submit button is clicked
    Page.Validate(((ImageButton)sender).ValidationGroup);

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnectString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_validateUsers", conn);
            //Input Values
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", Uname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", pwd.Text);
            //Return Values
            SqlParameter retParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
            retParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            SqlParameter acsParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ac_status", SqlDbType.Int);
            acsParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            SqlParameter nikParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@memb_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            nikParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            try
            {
                // Open Connection and execute Stored Proc
                conn.Open();
                ///////////SOMETHING GOES WRONG HERE///////////////
                cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Retrieve Data
                int retVal = (int)retParam.Value;
                string nickname = nikParam.Value.ToString();
                string ac_stats = acsParam.Value.ToString();

                if (retVal != 0)
                {
                    //Invalid Username or password
                }
                else
                {
                    //Login User
                }
            }

            catch (Exception Error)
            {
                lbl_login.Text = "An error occured, please try again later";
                debug.Text = Error.Message;
            }

            finally
            {
                debug.Text = "\n Clossing Connection";
                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I just want to receive the return value I simply use `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` I know how to receive data when I'm passing the SQL query to the SQL database, but it seems to be different when using Stored Procedures..

**EDIT**
Probably could improve this code further but it really does what it should do.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_validateUsers

@username varchar(10),
@password varchar(10),
@ac_status char(1) OUTPUT,
@memb_name varchar(15) OUTPUT

AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MEMB_INFO WHERE (memb___id = @username))
BEGIN
    SELECT @ac_status = ac_status, @memb_name = memb_name
    FROM MEMB_INFO
    WHERE (memb___id = @username) AND (memb__pwd = @password)
    RETURN 0
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    return 1
END
```

When I use break points to catch possible exceptions in Visual Studio, It gives me:
String[4]: The Size property has an invalid size of 0

Comment: What's the error you get when running `ExecuteReader`?

Comment: something about the string[4] being wrong size 0.

Comment: your string parameters need to have a length.

Comment: How stupid of me to over look that... Thanks! I knew it had something to do with those values up there, to think it was that simple..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you mentioned may be caused by the fact that you're not specifying the size of your `VarChar` parameters.  Instead of having lines like this:

```
SqlParameter nikParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@memb_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

Try this:

```
SqlParameter nikParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@memb_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a SqlDataReader.

From [Ins and Outs of using Stored Procedures in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dclark/InsOutsinCS11302005072332AM/InsOutsinCS.aspx)

> The SqlDataReader class is used to
>   read a forward only stream of records
>   returned from the database. The
>   SqlDataReader object is not
>   instantiated directly through a
>   constructor (hence the lack of the New
>   key word) but rather through the
>   ExecuteReader method of the SqlCommand
>   object. Before calling the
>   ExecuteReader method the connection to
>   the database is established using the
>   Open method of the SqlConnection
>   object.

Try

```
SqlDataReader drLogins;
Conn.Open();
drLogins = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: This was not the problem at all, Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

Your `@ac_status` is defined as integer in parameter. change it character or string.

```
SqlParameter acsParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ac_status", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Comment: My bad, but that changes the string[4] to string[3] Error :P